# Spark set active stages to 1

Tags: apache-spark

I'm processing a large query using spark dataframe and it takes so long to finish. And as I look into the active stages, spark is processing multiple stages. I'm just wondering if there's a configuration to set the number of running/active stages to 1 such that the spark processing will focus on 1 active stage.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to understand how Spark split jobs by stages and how it process them.

All stages inside one spark application will run sequentially. It's a DAG graph and each stage depends on its parent. So if you want to run multiple tasks (jobs) simultaneously you have to split your jobs into different applications and submit each of them.

And anything that causes a redistributing data among nodes will always create a new stage. So if you need to get one stage app you need to limit repartitioning of your data between nodes (maybe as said earlier by splitting your jobs into different applications or by rewriting some logic to decrease data shuffling).